# How to get SharePoint files properties present in a folder using Rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I want to list all files and it's properties present in a specific folder. I tried using below endpoint but it doesn't return file properties.

```
https://<tenant-id>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<folder relative path>')?$expand=Folders,Files,Properties
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
https://<tenant-id>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<folder relative path>')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Comment: it works!! thank you!